# How to create a batch file or a simple shortcut for a UNC path in windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, unc

I have to open a unc path very often. Its address is too long, which i have to type in the command line.
I was just thinking of some way i could create a shortcut for this.

Comment: Is it possible to narrow your question? There are numerous solutions for this, many of which target different use cases. (e.g. 'I need to open an Explorer window to this path' vs. 'I need to change cwd to this path' vs. 'I need to pass this path as part of another command.')

Answer (score 1):

Right click your desktop and select "new" then "shortcut", type in the full UNC path:

```
\\someserver\someshare\somefile
```

Ensure you have permission or you will still receive a login to the share.

Answer (score 0):

One way is mapping network drive: there is an option in Computer window.
Your `\\too\long\unc\path\that\you\open\very\often\` can become just `V:\often\`.